# SQL Server - Does dropping table will recover the used space

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need advise:

Database: HR (initial size:250mb)

In this we got two tables

Table 1: Employee (100mb)
Table 2: Employeebackup (125mb)

So as per above, we have still 25mb space available as per size we set for the database.

Now we drop the Employeebackup table, so will sql server recover the space (which is 125mb) and now making 150mb as available space.

Regards

Comment: Just noticed you've asked over 50 questions and not given anyone a single upvote. Quite shocking, sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should do. There may be *some* delay while SQL Server figures it out and does the necessary housekeeping in the background though.

If you want to recover the space on the disk in addition to recovering space available to the database, you'd then have to shrink the database.

You might also want to consider asking these kinds of questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ which is specifically for database related Q & A.